# C# - jQuery real-person allways fails

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-plugins, captcha

I use jQuery-realperson plugin.
However, the validate of captcha value at server-side, always fails.
I saw similar question at SO, but it was about problem that happen on PHP.
I need C# code.

**My client side - js, based on knoskout.js:**

```
   var validCaptcha = $.ajax({
                url: global.webApiConfig.getApiPath('Login/CheckCaptcha'),
                data: { Value: $('#captcha').data().realperson.hash, PersonValue: $('#captcha').val() },
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                async: false
            });
            if (validCaptcha.responseText != true.toString()) {
                vm.captchaError('invalid value');
                refreshCaptcha();
                return;
            }
```

**My server side - c#:**

```
  [HttpPost]
    public bool CheckCaptcha(CaptachaData dataForCheck)
    {
        int hash = 5381;
        dataForCheck.Value = dataForCheck.Value.ToUpper();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataForCheck.Value.Length; i++)
        {
            hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + dataForCheck.Value[i];
        }
        return dataForCheck.PersonValue != null &&  hash == dataForCheck.PersonValue.GetHashCode();
    }




public class CaptachaData
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string PersonValue { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the mistake!
You get hash code of orignial-value- twice!
once - at client side:

```
   $('#captcha').data().realperson.hash
```

and once- at server side:

```
   dataForCheck.PersonValue.GetHashCode()
```

you need to change at server side:

```
  return dataForCheck.PersonValue != null &&  hash.ToString() == dataForCheck.PersonValue;
```

Comment: From version 2.0.1 you can use getHash method. $("#captcha").realperson('getHash') instead of  $('#captcha').data().realperson.hash.